# Displaying remote errors with Parsleyjs V2

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

I just switched to using parsleyjs v2 from v1. Using remote validation was dead simple where I could just point to my api and pass back a `error` node with a description of the error to display to the user

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="" data-parsley-remote="/api/email/" data-parsley-required="1" data-parsley-trigger="focusout" maxlength="100" tabindex="5">
```

Example api error message:

```
{"error":"Invalid email"}
```

With version two there is no clear way of achieving the same thing with the abstracted [PARSLEY.REMOTE.JS](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/annotated-source/parsley.remote.html)

Any ideas how I should approach my issue of displaying api messages to the user?

Comment: This is currently not supported. I'll have to implement it back properly. Feel free to have a look too and submit a PR before I do.

Comment: +1 This was super simple with v1. I'm very tempted to go back to v1 if I can't solve this soon.